# Search text get "begins by" result first

Tags: sql, postgresql

My SQL request return text fields that begins by the reserch text:

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM mytable
WHERE field1 ILIKE 'ex%' OR UNACCENT(field2) ILIKE 'ex%'
```

And another request do the same, but without necessarily begins by the reserch text:

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM mytable
WHERE field1 ILIKE '%ex%' OR UNACCENT(field2) ILIKE '%ex%'
```

I'm looking for a way to return the results of the first request in first, and the results of the second request following, and if possible without duplicates results because the second request return also the results of the first request...

Or maybe we can just order "begins by" in first, and following the rest (not begins by) ?

Thanks for help

Comment: You can use `UNION`

Comment: But how duplicates results ? Can you show me an exemple ?

Comment: `UNION` will remove duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple have one query where you do `like '%ex%'`, to return all rows. Then add an `ORDER BY` that returns the `like 'ex%'` rows first.

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM mytable
WHERE field1 ILIKE '%ex%' OR UNACCENT(field2) ILIKE '%ex%'
ORDER BY field1 ILIKE 'ex%' OR UNACCENT(field2) ILIKE 'ex%' DESC
```

Comment: Nice one. Is that more efficient than an UNION between the two requests ?

Comment: This one is most probably faster.

Comment: @Macbernie . . . `UNION` still needs an `ORDER BY` to do what you want.  Hence, this is a better solution.